# compiling android kernel for mips

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel, mips, mips32

I have downloaded the mips android sources. But this includes a prebuilt kernel image "kernel-eb-qemu". When I gave "file kernel-eb-qemu", this was displayed:

"kernel-eb-qemu: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, with unknown capability 0x41000000 = 0xf676e75, not stripped"

Is this image specific for the emulator or can this be used on the actual hardware? If it cannot be used on the actual hardware, how do I compile the Android kernel for MIPS?(big endian, mips32 instructions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel-eb-qemu only works with the emulator.  You will need to build or obtain a linux kernel tailored for your actual hardware.  Your hardware manufacturer should have the information you need to build the kernel.